# How do I put this algorithm in programming languages (Python)

Tags: algorithm, implementation, pseudocode, polynomials

Here is an algorithm on evaluating polynomials

> ```
> //input---->p- polynomial
>             n- degree of p
>             a- the value at which to evaluate p(x)
> output: p(a)//
> function evaluate(p,n,a)
> begin
>  value=0.0;
> for i:=0 to n do
>  if p[i]!= 0.0 then
>    value=value+p[i]*a^i;
>  return value;
> end
> ```

How do I code this algorithm in a programming language (Python)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python it's

```py
def evaluate(p,n,a):
    value=0.0
    for i in range (0, n):
        if p[i]!= 0.0:
            value=value+p[i]*a**i
    return value;
```

Comment: (This is a painstakingly literal transcription. Sources for "opinions" about a/the "pythonic" one (and/or improving the algorithm) include [Code Review@SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).)